# What layer are the RIA Services DomainService classes

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

We're building a new system that will have more than one front-end, where (at least) one of them bing Silverlight.

We decided to use RIA Services as the Silverlight's service facade.

The question is, should we maintain another Service-Layer "behind" the RIA Services domainService classes or should we use it as our main Service-Layer?

Take in considerations that we have other front-ends not developed in Silverlight and will need to consume (for the most part) the same services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a domain service as a service layer. The data exposed by them can be consumed by any client since you can add OData endpoints.

You can also decide which entities to expose and even define new entities with less or different properties than the ones in your data layer.

This is the approach we're following in one of our projects (mid-sized) and it's been very good.

Comment: But what if I'll need to add aditional types of endpoints not supported  by the domainservice?  
The domainservices are forced to inherit from a specific type of object, and be exposed in certain way(s) both this things make me feel very uncomfortable as being properties of my Service Layer.  
What do you think?

Comment: Your domain service will be hosted in a standard web project. In case you need to add unsupported types of endpoints, you can always create new layers in that project that work as a bridge to your domain service.

Comment: Full disclosure, I work on the RIA team, but Alfonso's recommendation is a good place to start. You can add extra service pieces as needed, but it seems overkill to formalize it. Also, RIA exposes SOAP and JSON endpoints (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deepm/archive/2010/05/14/silverlight-tv-episode-26-exposing-soap-json-and-odata-endpoints-from-ria-services.aspx). In addition, the RIA team is working on a JavaScript client that should be useful for other, web-based clients (http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2011/04/13/RIAJS-jQuery-client-for-WCF-RIA-Services.aspx).